# VideoView plays a video in a device but not in another

Tags: android, h.264, mp4, android-videoview

I have a problem related with VideoView.

I have a H264 encoded video (inside a MP4 file) with a resolution of 1280x720. If I try to play it with a VideoView in my Samsung Galaxy S3, it works fine, but if I try the same video in a LG Optimus 2X, it just says "Sorry, this video cannot be played" (or something like that).

Both devices are running Android 4.0.4 (CM9 in the Optimus 2X, and stock rom in the Galaxy S3).

I don't know why one device plays it and the other doesn't. The only reason I can find is that VideoView won't play the video if the screen resolution is lower than the video resolution.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Android only are guranteed to support h264 encoded videos with a resolution of 480x360 px for any device running Android 3.0 and above.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html for more information.